# Is the Akuko plot ever revealed?

Tags: kamidori-alchemy-meister

During Chapter 7, Kohakuren takes Wil to a shrine where the head of a Kotenko who at one time must have been Kohakuen's Lover or even husband before ascending (he says that "it's the least I can do for my mate" at one point).

After reaching there, the Kotenko possesses Wil's body to speak to Kohakuren. One of the things they talk about is the growing danger of the Akuko and that their actions may be of a larger plan before the Kotenko asks Kohakuren to pass on a warning to 2 other (probably Senko like herself).

Now I've already completed the Yuela Route and Kohakuren is a requirement for the route because she is one of only 2 party members who has met Disna in person and act as mediator between him and Wil during the negotiations in currently, in the Sewari Route, since this quest about going to the shrine is on both routes, I would assume that it would also appear in the Emelita Route.

I am wondering, does this Akuko plot the Kotenko talks about get revealed in *Kamidori Alchemy Meister* or in any of Eushully's Games?

Comment: There is some elaboration in Quest 61, which should be available on all 3 routes starting in chapter 7 if Uya is in your party. Are you looking for something beyond that?

Comment: @LoganM i'll have to double check what Quest 61 is but i normally have all the guys run the store and the girls and large party members follow me so i may have missed what Uya adds, the exception to my party is Black Eushully who since i restarted everyone's levels in my 2nd playthrough leave behind cause i only recruited her to do the Orange Jelly quest because with a high enough sales value the new items Hannah sells can be resold at a high value in the shop thus allowing me to never have to worry the workshop fees

Comment: @LoganM what i'm looking for is if the Akuko go ahead with what they are planing and Will having to stop it, what is causing them to become more of a threat and possible meet the 2 people (Senko maybe) that the Kotenko asks Kohakuren to warn, ofcause there's the possibility that Eushully has yet to release a game that could have it in it

Comment: Pretty hard to say since I didn't complete emelita route . As far as I played (Yuela and Serwari) , I didn't find any information related to it.